# How do i use translate in the form using Zend?

Tags: zend-framework

```
<?php echo $this->translate("Hello World"); ?>
```

This works inside view. How do I get the same in the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Form, you can try this :

```
$this->getView()->translate("Hello World");
```